# Relation between Elo and search depth for basic minimax

Tags: engines, minimax

If we use the most basic approach to a chess engine (for example, for a codegolf): minimax to a fixed depth with the material count as static evaluation, then how strong is this algorithm?

This of course depends on the search depth, but since such engines have been implemented tens of thousands of times, I hope there are some resources that can say something about the strength as a function of the search depth. I haven't been able to find any so far.

It also depends on the material values, which are not always the same.